# Need specific dates in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, date, windows-forms-designer

I have an application in WindowsForms where I have to add exceptions if the day is 25th December and 1st January so  is something like this 
`if(DateTime.Now== 25thJanuary)`  I don't care about the year just the day, so is it possible for C# to get these days?

Comment: I believe what you want in your example is: `if(DateTime.Now== 25thDecember)` rather than `if(DateTime.Now== 25thJanuary)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if (now.Day == 25 && now.Month == 12)
```

you could check the day and the month of today like this

Comment: Though the answers look almost indentical, this answer would evaluate the same `DateTime.Now`. +10

Comment: @Ian when I wrote this, there wasnt a single answer there. So I didnt know if it was almost identical to another answer

Comment: @Mark ah, yes. I noted the answered time, and I believe your answer is slightly more robust against micro-seconds differences because you declared `now = DateTime.Now;` before process it while another answer evaluate two different `DateTime.Now` (albeit by micro-seconds difference) ;)

Comment: mmm sorry first time in here how do I mark one as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Easy. For checking 25th December you can do,

```
if(DateTime.Now.Month == 12 && DateTime.Now.Day == 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Diagonastics;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

DateTime now = DateTime.now;
if(now.Day == 25 && now.Month == 12)
{
  ....................
  //Put your code here
  ....................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two choose to find do is 25th December or 1st January. First is use `DateTime.Now` this is return not only day, is return and hours and minutes and seconds (for seconds I'm not sure).

In my example I use `DateTime.Today` who return Year Month and Day. and return default hour minutes and seconds.

```
if ((DateTime.Today.Month == 12 && DateTime.Today.Day == 25) || (DateTime.Today.Day == 1 && DateTime.Today.Month == 1))
{
     // do some stuff
}
```

I'm not sure but for performance maybe Today is better from Now because is not check what time is now. Today is check only what date is now (If we can talking here for performance).